# Loop through days and create custom week in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt    
start='2020-01-01'
end='2021-12-31'
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.date_range(start, end)})
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.day
df['Day_name'] = df[['Date']].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x['Date'], '%A'), axis=1)
```

I want to add another column to the df['wk'] that will loop trough the dates and create a custom week starting with a specific date.

For example Wk 1 will start from 2020-01-03, loop 7 days till  2020-01-09 and create wk 1, wk 2 will be from  2020-01-10 till  2020-01-16 and so on.  Always move 7 days

How can I do this in python

I am thinking it should be something like this:

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i,'wk']= row['Date'] + dt.timedelta(days = 7)
```

But this just adds 7 days to the current one, not stores the wk. I need a little guidance on how to do this

Comment: what should be the week for the values above `2020-01-03` ? should they be deleted?

Comment: I want to keep them. I accepeted your ansewer, Thanks a lot. I can make the year a variable and reset at the begining of 2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
#You can create the Day_name column without apply 
df['Day_name'] = df['Date'].dt.day_name()

#Solution starts here
week_start = '2020-01-03' #inout date
i = df.loc[df['Date'] == week_start,'Date'].dt.day_name().iloc[0]
df['wk'] = df['Day_name'].eq(i).cumsum()
print(df.head(12))
```

---

```
         Date  Day   Day_name   wk
0  2020-01-01    1  Wednesday  0.0
1  2020-01-02    2   Thursday  0.0
2  2020-01-03    3     Friday  1.0
3  2020-01-04    4   Saturday  1.0
4  2020-01-05    5     Sunday  1.0
5  2020-01-06    6     Monday  1.0
6  2020-01-07    7    Tuesday  1.0
7  2020-01-08    8  Wednesday  1.0
8  2020-01-09    9   Thursday  1.0
9  2020-01-10   10     Friday  2.0
10 2020-01-11   11   Saturday  2.0
11 2020-01-12   12     Sunday  2.0
```